# How do I use external libraries in an Erlang escript?

Tags: erlang

I want to write a throwaway Erlang script using `escript` that talks to a PostgreSQL database. How do I reference the `epgsql` application from my script?

If I simply `{ok, C} = pgsql:connect(Host, User, Pass, Opts)`, then I get `undefined function pgsql:connect/4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to have pqsql compiled (*.beam files). 
add this to your script to give arguments to the emulator

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -pa ../pgsql/ebin -Wall
```

see [escript doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html)

Answer (score 3):

As @locojay answered, you need that `-pa` line just after the shebang.

If you want a one-file escript however, I suggest you use `rebar escriptize` or have a look at [this line](https://github.com/fenollp/erl-mk/blob/master/erl.mk#L110).